# How to use relatively link in Fat-Free Framework

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

Now the webpage is `www.abc.com/a/b/c`

I want create a link to go to `www.abc.com/a/b/c/d`

But I don't want to use this `{{@BASE}}/a/b/c/d`

I want to use something like this `{{@BASE}}/{{@xxxx}}/d`

Can I completely use relatively link in Fat-Free Framework?

Comment: `{{ @BASE }}/{{ @PATH }}/d`?

Comment: is the F3 project at `abc.com` or is it at `abc.com/a/b/c`? If you question is about how to manage relative paths in subdirectories, please see https://github.com/bcosca/fatfree/wiki/FAQ#can-i-run-f3-in-a-sub-directory

Answer (score 1):

Use {{@PATH}}

From the user guide - PATH
Type: string, Read-Only

The URL relative to BASE. Default value: parse_url($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],PHP_URL_PATH)